# postfix and /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, postfix

What is correct file for /etc/hosts when running postfix mail server

my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      ubuntu-server.agadomarketing.com        ubuntu-server
```

my `/etc/hostname` is `mail.agadomarketing.com`

how must `/etc/hosts` look like that mail server will work correctly

now I changed to, is this correct?

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain                   localhost
84.255.253.186  mail.agadomarketing.com                 mail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks fine. You can have more than one alias on the same line though, if you want to keep the name ubuntu-server as well:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  localhost.agadomarketing.com
84.255.253.186  mail.agadomarketing.com mail ubuntu-server.agadomarketing.com ubuntu-server
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean but there is no rule how the hosts file must look for a postfix to work properly.

Instead you need an MX entry in your DNS server for the domain agadomarketing.com if you would like to start receiving email from this domain.

Comment: I have MX record, I just want to know if is /etc/hosts file correct. I am reading that is important for server how is /etc/hosts configuried